# How to use an exception?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw

In my CS class, we have to write a program that throws an exception if the user enters a negative number; the program should prompt the user to enter only positive numbers and then let them retype the number. But every time I throw an exception, my program gets suspended.

What am I doing wrong, or is there no way to continue a program if an exception is thrown? Does the program automatically get suspended when an exception is thrown?

```
    try{
    do
    {
        N = kb.nextDouble();
        if(N<0)
        {
            throw new NegativeArraySizeException();
        }
        else
            j++;
    }
    while(j==0);
    fill.size(N);
}
catch(NegativeArraySizeException e)
{
    System.out.println("The number you entered must be positive. Please try again.");
}
```

Comment: Have you Google'd *anything* at all?

Comment: I'd discourage using exceptions as program flow, as you're attempting to validate input from the user; this could be accomplished simpler (and cheaper) with a few if-statements.

Comment: Yes I did Google a lot,  but only got more confused when tutorials introduced throw vs throws and truth statements I think. My program would throw an exception,  but it would suspend after it threw it, all I needed was for the program to allow the user to reenter the information and maybe throw another exception if they entered another negative number.

Comment: And makoto, I would totally not use exceptions, but it's a requirement for this homework. I had tried many different attempts before resorting to asking for help on a forum. I think it was worth it because even if I did figure it out by trial and error,  I would not have understood it. Now I do.

Answer (score 1):

The `do-while` should wrap the `try-catch` statement:

```
do {
    try {
        //try to read number
    } catch (YourCustomException e) {
        //print message to user
    }
} while (<condition>)
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
Thank you Luiggi,
I figured it out.

```
j=0;
do
{
    value=kb.nextDouble();
    try
    {
        if(value<0)
            throw new NegativeArraySizeException();
        else
            j++;
    }catch(NegativeArraySizeException e)
    {
        System.out.println("The number you entered must be positive. Please try again.");
    }
}while(j==0);
fill.add(value);
```